# How to send `screen -X` command to the right user in a multi-attached session

Tags: gnu-screen

Let's say I want to bind a key sequence in GNU `screen` to jump to a specific window.  I might do so like this:

```
bind ^t exec screen -X select foo
```

(I've deliberately simplified this; the real-world application `exec`s a command which dynamically figures out which window to switch to, then runs the `screen -X` command.)

Great; this works well.  The problem comes when I've attached (via `screen -x`) to the same session from a different machine.  On the new machine, `^a^t` does as expected and switches to the window.  But, if I return to the original machine, leaving the new machine attached, then `^a^t` switches to the window *on the new machine*.  If I detach the new machine, everything goes back to working as normal.

Note that this is one session, so `-S` is of no use.  The session is not password-protected.  It also doesn't seem to relate to the `exec` machinery: while manually running `screen -X select foo` inside `screen` on the original machine works properly, running it in a separate terminal on the original machine (i.e. outside `screen`) still switches the window on the other machine.

How can I force `screen -X` to affect only the attached user on the same machine it's being run from?  (Affecting both users/machines would also be acceptable, if that's easier.)

Comment: How are you connecting to the session on *original machine* from *new machine*?

Comment: I'm just doing `ssh $orig_machine` and then, once logged in, `screen -A -x $screen_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `at` command should be a solution to what you are seeing. In the description for the `at` command in screen's man it says:

> **at** [identifier][#|*|%] command [args ... ]. 
> ...  
> In shared windows the command will be repeated for each attached display.  
> ...

Which sounds like it should switch the window in both places.

Comment: Yes! this works.  To be more clear, `screen -X at "$USER*" select foo` will do it for both displays.  To affect only one or the other, you have to work out what TTYs each one are running `screen` on.  Once you do that, you can do, say, `screen -X at pts/1% select foo` etc.